# Submitting HTML form using Jquery Ajax to check login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working with jquery ajax , html form , mysql and php. I have some registered users in the database. What I want to do now with the login form is; When someone click the submit button of the login form, serialize the form and make the isset() method true in the php file so that it can receive the sent data from the form. And check it with the database and return the user information but unfortunately its not working for me. Do any one know whats the problem . For now i have commented out the query from php, just to make clear that the form data is not echoing .

**Below is the Form**

```js
<form class="login-form" method="post" id="login-form">
              <div class="flow-text center-align">LOGIN</div>
              <div class="input-field col s12 ">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                <input id="icon_prefix" name="login_email" type="email" class="validate" required autocomplete="off">
                <label for="icon_prefix">Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">security</i>
                <input id="icon_prefix" name="login_pass" type="password" class="validate" required autocomplete="off">
                <label for="icon_prefix">Password</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <button type="submit" name="login_btn" id="lb" class="btn-flat waves-effect waves-blue-grey darken-4 right" > Submit <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> </button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

**Jquery Ajax, serializing the form**

```js
$("#lb").on("click",function(){
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "connections.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $("#login-form").serialize() + "&checkLogin=true",
            success: function(r){
                 console.log(r);
            }
        });  
    });
```

**The php file to receive login information**

```js
if(isset($_POST["checkLogin"]))   { 
     


 echo  $_POST["login_email"];
 echo  $_POST["login_pass"];
    


   //$sel_whole_tab = "SELECT * FROM fb_data WHERE user_email='$le' AND user_pass='$lp' ";
   //$q = $con -> query($sel_whole_tab);

   //if(mysqli_num_rows($q)>0){
 //    while($s_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){$curr_arr = $s_r;} 
 //    echo json_encode($curr_arr);     
   //}



}
```

Comment: You must describe, what is not working specifically. It's hard to understand `unfortunately its not working for me`. According to your code, you just submit your form with a submit button, not with ajax.

Comment: which is the connections.php file?

Comment: Are you storing passwords as plain text? That's a major NO-NO.

Comment: have you checked the network for the echoed values?

Comment: I am not submitting it, as i described , I want to check the login information with that of registered ones. For that i have to send the form data to the php. But the form data is not sending.

Comment: How do you see it? Check `Network` tab of your browser console.

Comment: Theres nothing shown @shukshin.ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should prevent form submit on click.

```
$("#lb").on("click",function(){        
    $.ajax({
        url: "connections.php",
        method: "post",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize() + "&checkLogin=true",
        success: function(r){
             console.log(r);
        }
    });  
    return false; // this one
});
```

It works, I see sent ajax request. Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/npdavsz9/

[image]

Comment: The example with your form works, it sends request. If your code doesn't work, you must have some different bugs.

Comment: Yeah its working, but why i cant collect it in here ... if(isset($_POST["checkLogin"]))   { 
    echo  $_POST["login_email"];
 echo  $_POST["login_pass"];
   }

Comment: I've modified the fiddle, check it. My `connections.php` file contains `if(isset($_POST["checkLogin"]))   {     echo json_encode(['email' => $_POST["login_email"], 'pass' => $_POST["login_pass"]]); } `. And it does return it, it is visible in the console.

Comment: Error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\ext_files\connections.php on line 50

Comment: By doing this , the error is gone, but no output ! if(isset($_POST["checkLogin"])) { 
  $c = array ( 'email' => $_POST["login_email"], 'pass' => $_POST["login_pass"] );
  echo json_encode($c);

}

Comment: I've just place this code to my connections.php. The example outputs it. Looks like you have additional bugs.

Comment: God, it was the prevent Default error, was stopping it from returning ! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#lb").on("click", function () {

                    alert('ok');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "connections.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data: $("#login-form").serialize() + "&checkLogin=true",
                        success: function (r) {
                            console.log(r);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,
In your JS

```
var str = $("#login-form").serializeArray();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "connections.php,  
    data: str,  
    success: function(value) {  
            console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrong. The `submit` event is not required to serialize.

Comment: Still not working, and btw the button works for me while submitting data into database

Comment: does the ajax call throw any error? Use  error: , like the success: to find that out.

Comment: I've changed the answer. Try serializing before ajax call and see.

Comment: It serializes the data , but how to collect it in the php now

Comment: The serialized entries will be just a string right. "varname=val&var2=val2"

Comment: Use $_POST["varname"]

Comment: @AlanPallath nup, not yet, this is my PHP now ! if(isset($_POST["login_email"]))   { 
     


 echo  $_POST["login_email"];

 echo  $_POST["login_pass"]; }

Comment: @Antesoft I thought it's a JQuery issue, don't know php much.